# Is it safe to cache amazon ec2 meta properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

To find out information about your ec2 instance, you can query certain values using "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/" + property.  Is it ok if these values are cached or are some values dynamic? Since there is a different URL for dynamic, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the [EC2 instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-categories) can change, such as:

- `public-hostname`
- `public-ipv4`
- `security-groups`
- `spot/termination-time`

Most values, however, will always stay the same.